# Protractor 'toContain' error

Tags: protractor

This is my expect:

```
expect(mandatoryFields[index].getAttribute('class')).toContain('error');
```

This is the error in console:

**Expected['formControl ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength error'] to contain 'error'.**

Eventhough the class contains ERROR class name, protractor is still throwing error. What could be reason? Any help!!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZvkuP/21/ 
 in this fiddle the same above code works, pretty confused

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZvkuP/22/
just by adding angular Brackets, it starts to fail. JuliRalp your help is needed here

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `toContain` try using `toMatch`. toContain is used to check whether the required value is present in an array or not. whereas toMatch uses regex for validating the text present in any value.

Comment: but I use this in the same spec file: "**expect(coBorrowerVisibility.getAttribute('class')).toContain('formInactive');**" which works fine. So if it works in this case, why it isnt working in above mentioned place

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a custom matcher in your beforeEach(), then calling `expect(mandatoryFields[index]).toHaveClass('error');`

```
jasmine.addMatchers([
toHaveClass: function () {
        return {
            compare: function (element, className) {
                return {
                    pass: element.getAttribute('class').then(function (classes) {
                        return classes.split(' ').indexOf(className) !== -1||classes.split(' ').indexOf(className+"\n") !== -1;
                    }),
                    message: "Expected elemenet to have class: "+className
                }
            },
            negativeCompare: function(element, className){
                return {
                    pass: element.getAttribute('class').then(function (classes) {
                        return classes.split(' ').indexOf(className) !== -1||classes.split(' ').indexOf(className+"\n") === -1;
                    }),
                    message: "Expected element not to have class: " + className
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```