# Promise returns the right mensagem using getText() but toContain() doesn't understand it

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I've trying to do an expect which contains some text but protractor keeps returning an error and I don't know why.

```
const validacao = element(by.tagName('app-notifications'));
   browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(validacao), 10000).then(() => {
   cadastroCargo.obterElementoPorTag('app-notifications').all(by.tagName('p')).getText().then(function (textoDaMensagem) {
     expect(textoDaMensagem).toContain("sucesso!");
                            
                        });
                });
```

the error is:

> Expected [ 'Cargo cadastrado com sucesso!' ] to contain 'sucesso!'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589630/protractor-tocontain-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toContain` is used for arrays.
That is why you are seeing `[]` along with the text 'Cargo cadastrado com sucesso!.

`toContain` is checking whether single element array with value 'Cargo cadastrado com sucesso! has value sucesso  in it . Which  it doesn't have and hence your assertion is failing

I guess `toMatch` would work in your case

Comment: `toContain` will work for string type as well. In this case he is using `element.all("p").getText()` which will return an array.

Comment: Yes , it would work. But in this case it has only one element